# Mostrar conteúdo da DIV clicando na imagem com slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando fazer com que ao clicar em uma imagem em questão oculte o título anterior e mostre o atual, e assim, sucessivamente. Já tentei usando `nextAll`, `return false` etc, mas acho que o problema está no aninhamento de classes, pois independente da imagem clicada deve aparecer o conteúdo em questão.

Por exemplo: Clicando na primeira imagem mostre o conteúdo do produto 1, clicando na próxima mostra o conteúdo do produto 2 e assim por diante (Apenas um por vez). Nesse [link](http://jsfiddle.net/d3nis/dL80ut7h/24/) do fiddle da pra entender melhor.

```js
$(".Titulo").hide();
$(".show_title").show();
$('div').click(function() {
     $(this).next(".Titulo").slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product-thumbs mb-xs-50">
   <h5 class="text-bold-300"><small>Outras Imagens</small></h5>
   <div class="owl-carousel owl-thumbs" data-slider-id="1"  style="display:inline; float:left;">
      <div class="owl-thumb-item show_title">
         //Clicando aqui aparecer texto do Produto 1
         <img width="20%" src="https://cdn.pling.com/img/d/c/0/2/e4fff450a6306e045f5c26801ce31c3efaeb.jpg" data-src="<?php echo$foto1 ?>" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="owl-thumb-item show_title">
         //Clicando aqui aparecer texto do Produto 2
         <img width="20%" src="https://cdn.pling.com/img/d/c/0/2/e4fff450a6306e045f5c26801ce31c3efaeb.jpg" data-src="<?php echo$foto2 ?>" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="owl-thumb-item show_title">
         //Clicando aqui aparecer texto do Produto 3
         <img width="20%" src="https://cdn.pling.com/img/d/c/0/2/e4fff450a6306e045f5c26801ce31c3efaeb.jpg" data-src="<?php echo$foto2 ?>" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>


 <div class="Titulo">
    <h2>Produto 1</h2>
    <p>Características</p>
</div>

<div class="Titulo">
    <h2>Produto 2</h2>
    <p>Características</p>
</div>

<div class="Titulo">
    <h2>Produto 3</h2>
    <p>Características</p>
</div>
```

Link do jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/d3nis/dL80ut7h/24/

Comment: Oi! :) Poderia tentar explicar um pouco melhor, por favor? Achei a pergunta um pouco confusa. **[Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/479526/edit)** a pergunta para acrescentar mais detalhes.

Comment: Editei, se ir no link do fiddle acho que da pra entender melhor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Da maneira que está construído o `HTML`, não é possível fazer do jeito que tentou, pois, o método **[next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)** precisa estar com os elementos aninhados para o seu correto funcionamento. Tem muitas maneiras de fazer o que quer, uma delas é colocando mais um **[data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)** nas `divs` e utilizá-lo como índice para fazer o controle de exibição com o método **[eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)**.

```js
$('.Titulo').hide();

$('.show_title').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.Titulo').hide();                       
  let indice = e.target.dataset.img;     // cria um índice a partir do data
  $('.Titulo').eq(indice).slideToggle(); // mostra o texto com o mesmo índice
});

$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel()
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="product-thumbs mb-xs-50">
  <h5 class="text-bold-300"><small>Outras Imagens</small></h5>
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-thumbs" data-slider-id="1">
    <div class="owl-thumb-item show_title">
      <img width="20%" src="https://cdn.pling.com/img/d/c/0/2/e4fff450a6306e045f5c26801ce31c3efaeb.jpg" data-img="0" data-src="<?php echo$foto1 ?>" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="owl-thumb-item show_title">
      <img width="20%" src="https://cdn.pling.com/img/d/c/0/2/e4fff450a6306e045f5c26801ce31c3efaeb.jpg" data-img="1" data-src="<?php echo$foto2 ?>" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="owl-thumb-item show_title">
      <img width="20%" src="https://cdn.pling.com/img/d/c/0/2/e4fff450a6306e045f5c26801ce31c3efaeb.jpg" data-img="2" data-src="<?php echo$foto2 ?>" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="Titulo">
  <h2>Produto 1</h2>
  <p>Características</p>
</div>

<div class="Titulo">
  <h2>Produto 2</h2>
  <p>Características</p>
</div>

<div class="Titulo">
  <h2>Produto 3</h2>
  <p>Características</p>
</div>
```

Comment: LeAndrade vê se vc consegue me ajudar nessa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/486997/pagina%c3%a7%c3%a3o-simples-com-javascript