# Paginação simples com Javascript

Tags: javascript, paginação

Fiz um sistema para listar boletos consumindo uma *API*, porém preciso gerar uma paginação simples (< Anterior Próximo >) passando o parâmetro *"lastEvaluated"* no *GET*. Se esse parâmetro existir, entrega o próximo lote de registros. Como poderia fazer isso, existe alguma função que de um atalho?

Array de Objeto:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "dueValue": 1964.56,
      "boleto": {
        "uri": "https://myurl/31263-7F6C1136-B1EF-40F4-AB5D-E2B969B94E0A.pdf",
        "digits": "99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999",
        "bank": "Itaú Unibanco S.A."
      },
      "doc": "108506",
      "dueDate": "2021-03-29",
      "payerDoc": "01010101010101",
      "representativeDoc": "020202020202"
    },
    {
      "dueValue": 503.67,
      "boleto": {
        "uri": "https://myurl/31260-BCA935EB-7060-466C-8415-980AE7AE596C.pdf",
        "digits": "99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999",
        "bank": "Itaú Unibanco S.A."
      },
      "doc": "108505",
      "dueDate": "2021-03-29",
      "payerDoc": "01010101010101",
      "representativeDoc": "020202020202"
    }

  ],
  "lastEvaluated": "b59372c2-9f77-4ab3-9394-1d98a8daa5be#2021-01-05" 
}
```

Código:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div style="padding:1em;">
        <h4>Boletos em aberto para o cliente <?php echo$nome ?></h4>
        <p>Clique em <strong>"<i class="far fa-file-pdf" aria-hidden="true"></i> Abrir"</strong> para imprimir seus Boletos.</p>
        <h5>Acesso válido para <strong>(<?php echo$datadia ?>)</strong></h5>
    </div>
  
    <div class="container">    
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-uppercase"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i> Data</th>
                    <th class="text-uppercase"><i class="fas fa-university"></i> Banco</th>
                    <th class="text-uppercase"><i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i> Valor</th>
                    <th class="text-uppercase"><i class="far fa-clone"></i> Dígito<span class="res digit-copied"></span></th>
                    <th class="text-uppercase"><i class="fas fa-barcode"></i> Boleto</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td id="demoData"></td>
                    <td id="demoBanco" class="text-uppercase blackFont"></td>
                    <td id="demoValue" class="greenFont"></td>
                    <td id="demoDigit" class="blackFont"></td>
                    <td id="demo"> </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- <div><small>Próximo > (Essa função está em desenvolvimento)</small></div> -->
        <div>
            <button id="anterior" disabled>&lsaquo; Anterior</button>
                <span id="numeracao"></span>
            <button id="proximo" disabled>Próximo &rsaquo;</button>
        </div>
    </div>


    <?php
        // test mode
        $vvv = "<div style='padding-top:10px;' class='container' id=\"objeto\"></div>";
        if ($vvv) {
           echo $vvv;
        }
    } 
    ?>

 <!-- <p style='padding-top:10px;' class='container' id="demoPagination"></p>  -->


</div><!-- /#wrapper -->
 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        var txt    = this.responseText;
        var objeto = JSON.parse(txt);
        
        // Checka Conteúdo
        b = objeto.items[0];
        var b;
        typeof b; 
        if ( typeof b === 'undefined' ) {  window.location.href = 'redirect.php?c=<?php echo $nome;  ?>';  }
        // Checka Conteúdo
        
        // Ordenando por data crescente
        // function custom_sort(a, b) {
        //     return new Date(a.dueDate).getTime() - new Date(b.dueDate).getTime();
        // }
        // objeto.items.sort(custom_sort);
        
        var contador=0;
        //init tloop
        objeto.items.forEach(item => { 

            var pData = document.createElement('tr');
            n = textContent = `${item.dueDate}`;
            var data = new Date(n);
            var dia  = data.getUTCDate().toString();
            var diaF = (dia.length == 1) ? '0'+dia : dia;
            var mes  = (data.getUTCMonth()+1).toString(); //+1 pois no getMonth Janeiro começa com zero.
            var mesF = (mes.length == 1) ? '0'+mes : mes;
            var anoF = data.getFullYear();
            var brData =  diaF+"/"+mesF+"/"+anoF;
            pData.append(brData);
            demoData.appendChild(pData);
            // Fim Data
 
            // Banco
            var tr3 = document.createElement('tr');
            o = textContent = `${item.boleto.bank}`;
            tr3.append(o);
            demoBanco.appendChild(tr3);
            // Fim Banco
            
            // Valor
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            v = textContent = `${item.dueValue}`;
            const valorFormatado = Intl.NumberFormat('pt-br', {style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'}).format(v)
            tr.append(valorFormatado);
            demoValue.appendChild(tr);
            // Fim Valor
 
            // Dígito
            var tr4 = document.createElement('tr');
            var tr4Copy = document.createElement('span');
            v4 = textContent = `${item.boleto.digits}`;
            tr4Copy.innerHTML = '<button class="btn btn-default btn-copy btn-copy"  data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Copiado">Copiar</button>';
            tr4.append(v4);
            tr4.append(tr4Copy);
            demoDigit.appendChild(tr4);
            $('.btn-copy').on('click', function() {
                try {
                    var cell = $(this).closest('tr')[0];
                    var selection = window.getSelection();
                    var range = document.createRange();
                    range.selectNodeContents(cell);
                    selection.removeAllRanges();
                    selection.addRange(range);
                    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
                    if (successful) {
                        // $('.res').html("Coppied");
                    
                    var alert = $('.res').html("<i class='far fa-copy'></i> Dígito Copiado");
                    alert.show();
                    setTimeout(function(){alert.html(''); }, 1500);


                    } else {
                        $('.res').html("Unable to copy!");
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    $('.res').html(err);
                }
            });
            // Fim dígito
      
            // Link Boleto
            var pDownload = document.createElement('tr');
            var rem = document.createElement("a");
            rem.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
            rem.setAttribute( 'href', item.boleto.uri);
            rem.setAttribute('style', 'text-decoration:none;color:black;'); 
            rem.innerHTML = '<i class="far fa-file-pdf" aria-hidden="true"></i> Abrir';
            // rem.textContent = '<i class="far fa-file-pdf" aria-hidden="true"></i> Abrir'; 
            pDownload.append(rem); 
            demo.appendChild(pDownload);
            // Fim Link Boleto

            // print all
            document.getElementById("objeto").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            // print all
      
 
        })  //end my loop
 

    }
};            
 
         
           
xhttp.open("GET", "https://myurl/v1/bills?order=desc&payer=<?php echo $cnpj; ?>", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("x-api-key", "-");
xhttp.send();
</script>
```

Tentativa:

Pensei em se o parâmetro *lastEvaluated* não for indefinido criar o botão próximo, no entanto não sei como vou atribuir no botão para que passe para o próximo lote e depois retorne, quando não existir mais o *lastEvaluated*.

```
    if (`${objeto.lastEvaluated}` !== 'undefined') {
        var button = document.createElement('button');
        button.setAttribute('type','button')
        button.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Próximo'));
        document.body.appendChild(button);            
    }
```

A URL que acessa o próximo lote fica assim:

```
xhttp.open("GET", "https://myurl/v1/bills?order=desc&lastEvaluated=b59372c2-9f77-4ab3-9394-1d98a8daa5be%232021-01-0&payer=<?php echo $cnpj; ?>", true);
```

**Esclarecimento do autor feito nos comentários:**

> Os registros do próximo lote sempre vem no parâmetro "lastEvaluated"
> EXEMPLO:
>
> ```
>  `xhttp.open("GET", "https://myurl/v1/bills?order=desc&lastEvaluated=b59372c2-9f77-4ab3-9394-1d98a8daa5be%232021-01-0&payer=<?php echo $cnpj; ?>", true);`
> ```
>
> acessa o próximo lote e assim por diante até quando não existir mais lotes dai
> o parâmetro não vem setado no array.
> Só é preciso atribuir isso nos botões de próximo e anterior de forma navegável.
> **PS: Não existe outro parâmetro na API.**

Comment: Pelo menos do meu ponto de vista não tenho informação suficientes sobre o código ou documentação dessa *API* para responder essa pergunta pois me parece ser necessário ou utilizar um parâmetro para mim ainda desconhecido ou  modificar o código dessa *API* para que trabalhe com um novo parâmetro na solicitação indicando se deseja obter o lote anterior ou lote seguinte a `lastEvaluated`.

Comment: os registros do próximo lote sempre vem no parâmetro "lastEvaluated"  EXEMPLO: xhttp.open("GET", "https://myurl/v1/bills?order=desc&lastEvaluated=b59372c2-9f77-4ab3-9394-1d98a8daa5be%232021-01-0&payer=<?php echo $cnpj; ?>", true);
acessa o  próximo lote e assim por diante até quando não existir mais lotes dai o parâmetro não vem setado no array. Só é preciso atribuir isso nos botões de próximo e anterior de forma navegável. PS: Não existe outro parâmetro na API.

Comment: denis, e quando clica no botão anterior, como a API sabe que é uma paginação anterior e não a próxima? se passar só `lastEvaluated` me parece que é como um cursor *forward only*, ou seja, só vai para a frente, "próximo". Em paginação geralmente passamos o número da página que queremos, por exemplo 1,2, 3, etc, e quem recebe (pode receber tbm o numero de dados a retornar) sabe calcular quais itens devem ser retornados para aquela página, mas  essa chamada de API do exemplo não tem isso ,como vai saber qual a próxima página? me parece que falta algo aqui pra resolver isso

Comment: ou "lastEvaluated" seria o primeiro item retornado? se fosse essa lógica até seria possível, mas estou especulando, precisa dessa informação, senão não tem como ajudar a fazer um paginador que vai para prox/anterior só com a informação da pergunta

Comment: Só para não restar dúvidas, como é formado a *url* da primeira consulta a que irá retornar o primeiro boleto? Pois esse não pode ser obtido fazendo a travessia por `lastEvaluated`.

Comment: @RicardoPontual é assim. Primeira Consulta = xhttp.open("GET", "https://myurl/v1/bills?order=desc&payer=<?php echo $cnpj; ?>", true); Caso exista outro lote, vem no array  o parâmetro lastEvaluated. EX:  "lastEvaluated": "b59372c2-9f77-4ab3-9394-1d98a8daa5be#2021-01-05"  Se vc colocar na URL esse parâmetro, ele vai pro outro lote EX: xhttp.open("GET", "https://myurl/v1/bills?order=desc&lastEvaluated=b59372c2-9f77-4ab3-9394-1d98a8daa5be%232021-01-0&payer=<?php echo $cnpj; ?>", true); Se existir outro lote ele vem com outro valor no lastEvaluated EX: "lastEvaluated": "BLABLABLA#2021-03-05"

Comment: @AugustoVasques a primeira consulta é xhttp.open("GET", "https://myurl/v1/bills?order=desc&payer=<?php echo $cnpj; ?>", true);  Caso existir outro lote, vem o parâmetro  lastEvaluated no array. Essa alternância entre próximo e anterior nos botões terá que verificar sempre o lastEvaluated pois para cada lote terá um valor diferente caso exista. Eu só consigo ver o próximo lote se eu insiro manualmente o  lastEvaluated na URL ficando assim:  xhttp.open("GET", "https://myurl/v1/bills?order=desc&lastEvaluated=b59372c2-9f77-4ab3-9394-1d98a8daa5be%232021-01-0&payer=<?php echo $cnpj; ?>", true);